# Can someone tell me why this Json is invalid?

Tags: json, validation

I have this **json**

> "Key1": [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,14,17,32,57,57,60,57,60,64,87,92,92,92,92,92,172,168,168,168,168,168,168,168,168,163,163,186,186,199,199,199,224,230,255,270,287,338,338,338,338,381,382,394,393,434,434,436,445,427,431,434,421,420,432,448,465,498,580,584,667,691,685,732,783,817,842,879,1001,1098,1143,1221,1265,1339,1401,1419,1519,1513,1581,1629,1604,1613,1571,1592,1532,1561,1656,1610,1561,1579,1383,1181,1120,1140,950,932,972,974,1060,1077,1113,1147,1200,1144,1191,1225,1260,1276,1333,1334,1273,1241,1287,1263,1338,1301,1303,1373,1292,1327,1338,1374,1369,1338,1334,1289,1230,1332,1309,1298,1258,1302,1328,1297,1233,1265,1247,1265,1300,1278,1271,1291,1320,1324,1367,1349,1382,1376,1389,1379,1433,1429,1462,1525,1405,1429,1406,1360,1383,1438,1383,1414,1385,1372,1387,1389,1349,1401,1400,1272] , "Key2" : [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,4.38,2.55,-0.63,-1.01,-1.62,-4.45,2.68,2.86,3.34,-0.41,1.5,2.58,-0.36,-0.56,-4.39,-3.7,0.65,-4.71,4.69,6.59,-1.95,0.67,-0.37,-0.78,4.49,4.56,1.25,1.13,1.54,1.3,3.64,1.07,2.94,1.45,1.65,-0.49,-2.09,0.88,1.44,-2.83,-0.41,2.95,1.09,3.79,1.81,-0.65,2.27,-1.42,-1.58,2.49,2.71,3.25,1.87,2.38,-2.05,1.9,2.53,4.99,-0.53,2.16,1.94,-1.12,-0.5,-0.21,1.84,0,2.32,2.02,1.04,1.65,0.96,1.01,2.82,2.82,0.17,0.3,-0.88,3.17,2.87,-2.12,0.71,-3.96,1.62,-2.89,5.17,2.68,-2.48,-2.4,-0.42,-12.74,-13.34,-5.11,1.98,1.61,-1.92,4.15,6.32,8.35,1.21,5.15,2.47,4.5,-2.59,3.26,2.68,-1.53,1.06,3.81,0.19,-4.62,-2.45,3.61,-1.77,5.03,3.18,-0.18,4.57,0.38,1.78,0.65,1.65,-0.89]

Getting error when validating at http://jsonlint.com/

```
Parse error on line 1:
"Key1" : [null,
^
Expecting '{', '['
```

Can anyone help me identify issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Valid JSON is either an object or an array. So the JSON should always start with `{` or `[`. In your case you got neither. You just have a property named 'Key1', which doesn't belong to anything.

Try this:

```
{"Key1": [null,null,null,"etcetera"]}
```

The result is an object that has one property, Key1, which is an array containing all your values.

As T.J. Crowder points out, [rfc7158](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7158) suggests that a valid document doesn't have to be an object or an array, but can be any of the supported JSON type values (string, boolean, etc). However, http://JSONLint.com doesn't support this yet. Anyway your document is still invalid, since it doesn't consist of a single value, but of a property declaration (with the colon separating the property name and its value). Such a declaration must always be part of an object.

See http://www.json.org/ for more details about JSON notation.

Comment: *"Valid JSON is either an object or an array."* Actually, they've dropped the requirement that the top level be an object or an array. That used to be true, but now any complete valid JSON production is valid on its own. E.g., `"foo"` is a valid standalone bit of JSON now, whereas a few years back it wasn't. The answer is still correct, of course, because what the OP has *isn't* a complete valid production, it's only part of one.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for that addition. Indeed, the problem in this case is that it's not a complete production, but only a property + value, which must be part of an object. A stand-alone string like "foo" could be valid. JSONLint (or at least http://jsonlint.com/) doesn't accept that, though.

Comment: JSONLint must be slightly out of date. As I say, it *used* to be that there was this distinction between JSON "documents" and JSON "fragments," but it wasn't a useful distinction and has been dropped.

Answer (score 1):

That is because your JSON is invalid and what you have to do to fix it is given in the error message. You have to enclose your string with { } or [ ].

Ex:

`{"Key1": [null,null,null,14,17,32]}
[{"Key1": [null,null,null,14,17,32]}]`

You can validate JSON strings using [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) and it will show you if it contain errors.